# Django- CSS is not working for other pages such as header tags

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have linked my css file in 'main/static/css/style.css' and my pages are in 'main/templates/main/pages.html'.
But the CSS is not working for some pages such as the h2 tag is not taking the style.

### base.html

> `{% load static %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">`

### privacy.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="main">
    <h1><b>Privacy</b></h1>
    <div style="height:35px" aria-hidden="true"></div>

    <div class="text_para">

        <h2 class="h2_privacy">Mission</h2>
        <p>paragraph<p> 
.......
```

### style.css

```
.main {   
    -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 70%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

.text_para {
    margin-right: 5%;
    text-align: justify;
}

/*heading h2 for privacy page*/
.h2_privacy {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Lucida Calligraphy', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: @ xtranger grx10 , your css is working for other classes? like other classes it does work but not in h2 tag--right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I was inactive and thank you.

And yes I have found the answer on stack overflow itself, actually I don't close my tabs so I think every time I refresh the page it does not refresh totally.

I just had to do `ctrl + f5` to bypass the cache and the css would load with the updates.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure CSS is loading properly (e.g. check from network section of browser dev tool).

Second you need to make sure the element is in the page and has the correct class matching CSS file.

Check these two and update your question if you didn't find the problem.